# After Changes in rights from admin Check if the end user is logged in and log him out of application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi everyone here is my question, if the admin changes rights for a specific user, is it possible for the application to check if that user is logged in at the moment and if yes perform a logout operation for him in order to refresh his rights.

Answer (score 0):

use form authentication and just clear the session it should do the trick

```
FormsAuthentication.Signout()

Roles.DeleteCookie();
Session.Clear();
Response.Resirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl)
```

for details

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx

Comment: This will logout the current user from this and clear this session. I need to check if the other user whose rights admin has changed is currently logged in and log him out.